# Smooth scroll not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to make smooth scroll on my web page.I think that error is in this line but i don't know how to fix it.

```
a[ id= "menu" ]:target ~ .panel {
  -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
  transform: translateY( 0px );
}
```

I want it to scroll smoothly instead of just jumping to that div. Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZv3K/1/) example

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `<a>` element with an id of `menu` in your markup.

Comment: There is, in the 4th row in HTML.

Comment: That's an `<a href="#menu">`, not an `<a id="menu">`. Not the same kind of beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this code:

```
$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#menu").offset().top
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZv3K/2/)

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work on my app. Where exactly should i include jquery, maybe that is the problem. And can i use jquery i have already included 1.11.0?

Answer (score 0):

It adds a smooth scroll effect :

Add this script code in your page

```
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });

});
```

Comment: Try to put it inside that jsfiddle, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you haven't added Jquery library in your code. You will have to add it.

Comment: Add this in your HTML part in js fiddle : <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You are to trying to scroll your Slider or Section Smoothly,
It can be done through animate() or else you can alse try to show your section like:

```
show({"right":"1000px"}, 1000);
```

Next way is to use smoothDivScroll()

```
Source:  http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/    

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scrollablediv").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
    });
});
```